# ASP.NET Identity retrieving User's Email by UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET MVC application users can post projects and they will be store in the DB. As usual, there is an Index view for the projects where users can see the list of all the projects available, along with some action links beside them (Details/Apply).
When a user clicks on the "Apply" action link, he is asked to fill in some words about why he wants to participate (cover letter). After he submits, an Application is stored inside the database containing a unique `ApplicationId`, the user's `UserId` and the `ProjectId` that he is applying to so I can keep track of all the applications.

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CoverLetter { get; set; }
}
```

In the "Details" view, all the project's data is being displayed, and managed to get it to display all the cover letters and the userId's that applied for this project.

```
Cover letters:
@foreach (var item in Model.Applications)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br/>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoverLetter) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The `UserId` and `CoverLetter` from the Application is retrieved successfully, however what I need is based on the `UserId` to retrieve the user's name and email from the database.

Edit: here is the entire ProjectsController:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using Leepio.Models;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace Leepio.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Projects
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole, studentRole")]
        public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string SortBy, string Page)
        {
            ViewBag.SortOrder = SortOrder;
            ViewBag.SortBy = SortBy;
            var projects = db.Projects.ToList();




            var model = new ApplicationTwoViewModel
            {
                Model1 = new List<Project>(projects),
                Model2 = new Application
                {

                    UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    ProjectId = 11,
                    CoverLetter = "asdf",
                    ApplicationId = 23,
                }
            };

            switch (SortBy)
            {
                case "Title":
                 switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "ApplicationDeadline":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDeadline).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDeadline).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "Duration":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "HourlyRate":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.HourlyRate).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.HourlyRate).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "TotalProjectCost":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.TotalProjectCost).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalProjectCost).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "City":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.City).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.City).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "RequiredPresencePercent":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.RequiredPresencePercent).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequiredPresencePercent).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Language":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Language).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.Language).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "RequiredSkills":
                    switch (SortOrder)
                    {
                        case "Asc":
                            projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.RequiredSkills).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "Desc":
                            projects = projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.RequiredSkills).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList();
                    break;
            }



            ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(db.Projects.ToList().Count()/10.0);
            int page = int.Parse(Page == null ? "1" : Page);
            ViewBag.Page = page;
            model.Model1 = projects;    
            model.Model1 = model.Model1.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
            return View(model);

        }



        private UserManager<IUser<>  userManager;


        // GET: Projects/Details/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole, studentRole")]
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Create
        [Authorize(Roles= "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Projects/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserId,ProjectId,Title,ApplicationDeadline,Duration,HourlyRate,TotalProjectCost,City,RequiredPresencePercent,Language,RequiredSkills,Description")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                project.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projectts/Edit/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProjectId,UserId,Title,ApplicationDeadline,Duration,HourlyRate,TotalProjectCost,City,RequiredPresencePercent,Language,RequiredSkills,Description")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (project.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
                { 
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return HttpNotFound("Project is not yours!");

            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // GET: Projects/Delete/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        // POST: Projects/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "companyRole")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
            {
                db.Projects.Remove(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpNotFound("Project is not yours!");
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I actually need to change anything inside the `ApplicationController`? I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: After finding the project. use the project's `UserId` to get the user object from the `UserManager.FindByIdAsync`. You'll need to modify your return model to pass that information back to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, much more simple.

Inside the ProjectsController Details GET method :

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
    var user = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(project.UserId);
    ViewData["user"] = user.Result.Email;

    if (project == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(project);
}
```

Basically retrieving the entire User entity inside the 'user' var.
Then I just send it to the view with ViewData["user"] = user.Result.Email;

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Applications)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoverLetter) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @ViewData["user"])
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I initialized the UserManager as so:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ProjectsController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{

}

public ProjectsController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}

public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to modify your `ApplicationController`. After finding the `Project`, use `Project.UserId` to get the associated `User` from the Identity framework like...`UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId)`.

You'll need to modify your returned model to pass that information back to your view, but it is possible to achieve what you are requesting.

Given your current `Application` class you can create a new model from scratch or via inheritance, adding the properties you need for your view...

```
public class ProjectDetailsApplicationModel : Application {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

...The above show the model via inheritance.

You can then create a view model for your view that holds all the information you need to show the needed details...

```
public class ProjectDetailsModel {
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsApplicationModel> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Now you indication that you are using Asp.Net-Identity framework so given that assumption your `ProjectsController` can be modified to something like this...

```
public class ProjectsController : Controller {
    private ApplicationDbContext db;
    private ApplicationUserManager userManager;

    public ProjectController() {
        this.userManager =  new ApplicationUserManager();
        this.db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity

    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

        if (project == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        //construct model...                    
        var model = new ProjectDetailsViewModel {
            Project = project,
            Applications = await BuildApplicationModels(project.Applications)
        }

        return View(model);
    }
    private async Task<IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsApplicationModel>> BuildApplicationModels(IEnumerable<Application> applications) {
        List<ProjectDetailsApplicationModel> result = new List<ProjectDetailsApplicationModel>();
        foreach (var application in applications) {
            var model = new ProjectDetailsApplicationModel {
                ApplicationId = application.ApplicationId,
                ProjectId = application.ProjectId,
                UserId = application.UserId,
                CoverLetter = application.CoverLetter
            };

            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(application.UserId);
            if (user != null) {
                model.UserName = user.UserName;
                model.Email = user.Email;
            }
            result.Add(model);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can then reference the User's name and email in the view...

```
@model: ProjectDetailsModel

<!--...other markup...-->

Cover letters:
@foreach (var item in Model.Applications)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br/>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoverLetter) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I am afraid I cannot find IUserManager anywhere? the IdentityUser.cs file only contains "public class IdentityUser etc...". I've posted the full ProjectsController, it is quite lengthy.

Comment: I am having trouble initializing the IUserManager userManager basically. are you sure it is not called something else?

Comment: `IUserManager` was just a concept interface not an actual class unless you created your own abstraction. You indicated that you are using Identity framework so there should already be a UserManager class somewhere in the project for you to use to get user information. Where are you storing userName and email?

Comment: IdentityModels.cs has a public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser. Im not sure what I should use, User.Identity.GetUserId(); ?

Comment: However wouldn't this retrieve the current user's ID ?

Comment: That would be correct. What you said you wanted was the other users names and email.

Comment: Yes. I can retrieve the application's UserId just fine. However only the UserId is stored into the Application, not their Email, and was hoping I can retrieve their email from the AspNetUsers database table based on their ID's.

Comment: Yes you can. You do that using the `UserManager`. Given you have an `ApplicationUser` class. look for `ApplicationUserManager` That is the class that will allow you to get the users in the database.

Comment: So I should be using  private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private ApplicationUserManager userManager; right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. In my answer I basically abstracted the `ApplicationDbContext` and  `ApplicationUserManager` behind the `IDbContext` and `IUserManager` interfaces respectively and injected them into the controller. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, now I got it! When trying to open the Projects index I get a "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." error? On the stack it says  " An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Leepio.Controllers.ProjectsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Comment: Ok that error is because you are not using Dependency Injection. Then in that case go back to declaring and instantiating those classes internally. You probably are not ready for DI as yet. Do I need to update my answer or do you understand what you need to do.

Comment: @crystyxn, I updated answer. If this answer was useful to you, please up vote. If it resolves your issue remember to mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: did you mean to remove the "this." in public ProjectController() {
        this.userManager =  new ApplicationUserManager();
        this.db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    } ? Also ApplicationUserManager(); gives an error - there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'store' of 'ApplicationUserManager.ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>)'  I do not understand this error.

Comment: You need to go read up on how to use Asp.Net Identity. I am trying to assist you not do the work for you. If you have an `AccountsController` take a look at how the dbcontext and usermanager are used there and try to apply the same concept in this controller.

Comment: Alright thank you so much for your help! have a great day

Comment: Same to you. Happy coding.

Comment: I kind of got it to work adding the following code inside the ProjectsController: http://imgur.com/VJLIYZb and getting this strange error when trying to click on Details of a project. http://imgur.com/mv04IOV Any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111452/discussion-between-nkosi-and-crystyxn).